# HTML / jQuery select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, web-applications

I am confused with `<select multiple="multiple">`.

I have this `select`:

```html
<select id="id_users" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="users">
        <option value="2">John</option>
        <option value="3">Danee</option>
        <option value="4">Panos</option>
        <option value="5">Mary</option>
</select>
```

By default, in order to select multiple options, you have to press Ctrl and left-click each option. Ok, I get that.

What I want is, each time I **click** an option, this option gets selected. And by selected, I mean I need it to stay highlighted.

I have tried multiple ways to iterate through the select, but in every way, the last one I have clicked stays highlighted (even though I have changed its .attr() to .attr('selected',true), and in my Firebug console, it seems to have changed to selected).

I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: You must try using [Multiple Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select)

Comment: Hi Developer, You can use Bootstrap for a ez layout and a ez multi select http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-multiselect/ good luck and ask me if you need help.

Comment: If I got that right, you just want to prevent deselect on click for already selected options? So that 'click option' = 'always select option'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally went with http://loudev.com/#home , which is a terrific pluggin!!!

Thanks again @nisar for the suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is not the default behavior of a multiple select.

You must use the same action (Ctrl key + left-click each option) every time you want to modify the selected items. If you attempt to click an individual item, it reverts back to the original action of a single select which is to *select a single item*.

If you are willing to use Javascript,
you can override this behavior. The following code would effectively do a single click select:

```
$("option").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop("selected", !$(this).prop("selected"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you are looking for multiple selected dropdown , check here [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri)

```
$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
```

otherwie use multiselect js, [multiselect js](http://loudev.com/#home)

Comment: This is a very good idea but it will not work for me. I need it to be <select>.